# How to use or operator on object when having error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

So I tried to give null for the error message, but it shows

```
 if(err){
            res.status(403).json({
              emailErr: err.errors.email.message || null,
              userErr: err.errors.username.message || null,
            });

TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
```

Comment: Carefully read the error message. The error says that either `email` or `username` is `undefined`. The `|| null` would only work when the content of `.message` is a falsy value

Answer (score 0):

Normally, JavaScript errors out if you try to access a property on `undefined` like in this lookup chain. You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to tell JavaScript to expect it:

```js
if (err) {
    res.status(403).json({
        emailErr: err.errors.email?.message || null,
        userErr: err.errors.username?.message || null,
    });
}
```